# Is there an easy to use Bible program for both OS X and iOS?

Tags: software-recommendation, software

Is there an easy to use Bible program, preferably with dictionary, concordance as well as text for maybe more than 1 translation.

My PC has PC Study Bible and it's great but I've grown to hate Parallels.

Tried Macsword and bombed out, too complicated for me.

Answer (score 2):

### [Logos Bible Software](http://www.logos.com/apps)

For both Mac and iOS, as well as Windows, Android, and web based. It has several different versions, some are paid, and some free. It allows you to search within a Bible. Other features include Bible words studies, passage guides, highlighting, and reading plans

[iOS App Store Link](http://itunes.apple.com/app/bible!/id336400266?mt=8) (iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch compatible)
[image: Logos bible on iOS]
[Logos for Mac](http://www.logos.com/mac)
[image: Logos for Mca]

Answer (score 2):

### Top Choices for Mac Bible Software

There are many Bible programs for the Mac.

---

- [Logos Bible software](http://www.logos.com/mac)  Fairly easy to use but also somewhat expensive.
  [image: Logos Bible Software]

---

- [Accordance](http://www.accordancebible.com/)  I have heard that this is the best and most powerful of them, and there is a free version.
  [image: Accordance Bible Software]

---

- [OliveTree](http://www.olivetree.com) This is what I use (mostly on my iPad) and I love it.
  [image: Olive Tree for Mac]

You can find other links to software [here.](http://onsoftware.en.softonic.com/the-best-free-bible-software-for-mac)

Answer (score 1):

This is the ridiculously simple answer, but I don't use a special bible reader program; I use built-in operating system features and a high quality text editor.

I constructed a text file called `Bible.txt` that I open in TextWrangler. The editor's search features function well as a concordance, and for multiple translations, I open additional text files in additional windows. Thanks to the wonders of Unicode, it even works for Hebrew and Greek versions.

I have chapter breaks set up with hard `\n` characters, and verses separated simply by verse numbers, so each line is a chapter.

It doesn't have a *bible* dictionary, but three-finger tap on my trackpad brings up the Mac OS X Dictionary, which includes Wikipedia pages that are quite helpful about names of people, places, events, etc.

On the iOS side, I use iBooks. Not as full-featured as the Mac side, but I mostly read there, and don't do a whole lot of active sermon writing on my iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Blue Letter Bible](http://www.blueletterbible.org/) (Mac/OSX).  Different versions for side x side comparison.  Great iPhone and and iPad Apps.  Has great commentaries (written and Audio).  The Apps is where I believe it does the best job. It's free, donations are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for synchronization between devices as a key feature, then you could consider using a Kindle bible. Then you've got a web interface, iPad, and iPhone interface that synchronizes your personal notes and highlights. It unfortunately won't have a lot of the other features you're looking for.